# I'm getting a typesript error when I try to use props, is there a way to fix this?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, routes, react-props

I'm getting a typesript error when I try to use props. When I hover over the underlined error in the home route path, `*features*={features}`, I get a no overload matches this call. I think this issue has something to do with props, although the error I'm getting is (below). I would be incredibly grateful for any help.

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: (RouteProps<"/", {}> & OmitNative<{}, keyof RouteProps<string, { [x: string]: string | undefined; }>>) | Readonly<RouteProps<"/", {}> & OmitNative<...>>): Route<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ path: "/"; component: FC<HomeProps>; features: any; exact: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route<{}, "/">> & Readonly<RouteProps<"/", {}> & OmitNative<{}, keyof RouteProps<...>>> & Readonly<...>'.
      Property 'features' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route<{}, "/">> & Readonly<RouteProps<"/", {}> & OmitNative<{}, keyof RouteProps<...>>> & Readonly<...>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: RouteProps<"/", {}> & OmitNative<{}, keyof RouteProps<string, { [x: string]: string | undefined; }>>, context: any): Route<{}, "/">', gave the following error.
    Type '{ path: "/"; component: FC<HomeProps>; features: any; exact: true; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route<{}, "/">> & Readonly<RouteProps<"/", {}> & OmitNative<{}, keyof RouteProps<...>>> & Readonly<...>'.
      Property 'features' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Route<{}, "/">> & Readonly<RouteProps<"/", {}> & OmitNative<{}, keyof RouteProps<...>>> & Readonly<...>'.
```

This is my code for further reference

```
import React, { FC, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Sidebar from "./components/Sidebar";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Order from "./pages/Order";
import History from "./pages/History";
import "./App.css";

import GeoJSON from 'ol/format/GeoJSON'

const App: FC = () => {

  const [ features, setFeatures ] = useState<any>([])

  useEffect( () => {

    fetch('/mock-geojson-api.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then( (fetchedFeatures) => {

        const wktOptions = {
          dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
          featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
        }
        const parsedFeatures = new GeoJSON().readFeatures(fetchedFeatures, wktOptions)

        setFeatures(parsedFeatures);

      })

  },[])

  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Sidebar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} features={features} exact />
          <Route path="/order" component={Order} />
          <Route path="/history" component={History} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I took out some of the comments from the earlier post to save space. From the earlier post, one of the users said the problem was related to the props which were being sent through the features. So I decided to include the  Home component which is being imported and providing the props.

```
import { FC } from "react";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./mapwrapper.css";

import Map from "ol/Map";
import View from "ol/View";
import TileLayer from "ol/layer/Tile";
import VectorLayer from "ol/layer/Vector";
import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector";
import XYZ from "ol/source/XYZ"; //here...

import { fromLonLat } from "ol/proj";
import Geometry from "ol/geom/Geometry";

type HomeProps = { features: any[] };

const Home: FC<HomeProps> = (props) => {
  const [map, setMap] = useState<Map>();
  const [featuresLayer, setFeaturesLayer] = useState<VectorLayer<VectorSource<Geometry>>>();
  
  const mapElement = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const mapRef = useRef<{}>();
  mapRef.current = map;

  useEffect(() => {
    const initalFeaturesLayer = new VectorLayer({
      source: new VectorSource(),
    });

    const seoul = [126.97794, 37.56629];
    const seoulWebMercator = fromLonLat(seoul);

    // create map
    const initialMap = new Map({
      target: mapElement.current!,
      layers: [

        new TileLayer({
          source: new XYZ({
            url: "http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&hl=en&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}",
          }),
        }),

        initalFeaturesLayer,
      ],
      view: new View({
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        center: seoulWebMercator,
        zoom: 16,
      }),
      controls: [],
    });

    setMap(initialMap);
    setFeaturesLayer(initalFeaturesLayer);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.features?.length && featuresLayer) {

      featuresLayer.setSource(
        new VectorSource({
          features: props.features, // make sure features is an array
        })
      );

      map?.getView().fit(featuresLayer.getSource().getExtent(), {
        padding: [100, 100, 100, 100],
      });
    }
  }, [props.features, featuresLayer, map]);


  return (
    <div>
      <div ref={mapElement} className="map-container"></div>

    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass `features={features}` as prop in the Route component because it doesn't have that prop.

If you have to pass additional data to the `Home` component you can use other strategies, e.g. you could create a hook that fetch the `features` data and use it inside the `Home` component.